# siunitx automatically rounds the values?

Tags: siunitx

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}       % nice alignment for decimals

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
    >{$}c<{$} 
    | S[table-format=-1.4]S[table-format=-1.4] 
    | S[table-format=-2.4]S[table-format=-1.4] 
}
    w_1  &  0.0001 & -0.0001 & -0.0000  & 0.0000  \\
   %w_1  &  0.0001 & -0.0001 & {-}0.0000  & 0.0000  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How can I ensure that `-0.0000` does not lose its *negative* sign at front?
As I have rounded the values, this minus sign is important.

But `siunitx` seems to have *rounded* it too??

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make sense. If the data are only accurate to 4 decimal places then the negative reading on the original is meaningless. Either don't round or accept that when you do the result has to be logical. (Not a technical factor, of course.)

Comment: Why can't you insert the number with more precision and let *siunitx* do the rounding? That way you would have consistent rounding in the whole document.

Comment: @JosephWright I am not sure if I understand. Maybe I did not express my self clearly. My raw data is accurate up to 15 decimal places. But I have a large table, I have decided to present it only up to 4dp. This particular value is 3.332 x 10^(-7).

Comment: @hbaderts I never knew that. I will have a go with it!

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Zero is zero: it's not got a sign. I don't know of any data accurate to 15 figures, and if you have a small number with lots of leading zero digits you should be giving it in an appropriate exponent for (as you just have here!).

Comment: @JosephWright I am typing up some estimated values from an optimization, which has a constraint say a<0. The optimization gives that a is -3.332 x 10^(-7). All other values are just about form x.xxxxxxxx (up to 15 decimals) away from 0. So in a Table, I have presented them up to 4 decimals. With this particular value, all I want to do, is to show a is -0.0000, with the emphasis that it is a negative value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *siunitx* package for rounding the numbers instead of doing this manually. That way you can enter the original number and setup siunitx to round according to your needs. This allows for a consistent rounding and number formatting throughout the document and allows to easily change the precision if desired. You can find detailed information in the package documentation.

You can specify either a number of decimal places (`round-mode=places`) or a number of significant figures (`round-mode=figures`). The number of digits or figures is set using the `round-precision` option.

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{round-mode=places, round-precision=4}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
    >{$}c<{$} 
    | S[table-format=-1.4]S[table-format=-1.4] 
    | S[table-format=-2.4]S[table-format=-1.4] 
    }
    w_1   &  0.0001 & -0.0001 & 0.000000001 & -0.000000001  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]